# Android API 19 (4.4.2)Scanning BLE sensortag

Tags: android

I am learning Android programming and i got some problems about BLE sensortag scanning. SONY API19(4.4.2), BLE sensortag used, all real device. I tried  `mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);` and `mBluetoothAdapter.startScan(mLeScanCallback);` two ways to scan BLE sensortag but failed.

Comment: BLE samples provided by Google works like a charm. Did you try them?

Comment: Yes, i import offical BLE sample and it can scan and find device, but in java code, mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback); function still was deprecated.    Android offical webpage announced "This method was deprecated in API level 21. use startScan(List, ScanSettings, ScanCallback) instead. " and i tried ,but does work.